# Select an nth matched node from a list of matching nodes

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I'm working with selenium to perform some automation and I'm attempting to interact with my webpage using Selenium & CSS selectors.

My question is how do I select the nth matched node returned from a list of all matching nodes?

For example my CSS selector is ".contactName" which returns 2 matching nodes. Using Selenium I want to do something like

```
selenium.Click("css=.contactName the second match");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I ended up using in order to select the second input with the class name

```
selenium.Click("xpath=(//input[@class='contactName'])[2]");
```

Comment: Note: Indexes for xpath starts with 1 and not 0. so **nth** should be greater than 0

Answer (score 2):

Do these two nodes share the same parent? If so, you can try one of these, depending on where they are under their parent in the DOM and whether there are any other kinds of elements:

```
selenium.Click("css=.contactName:nth-child(2)");
selenium.Click("css=.contactName + .contactName");
selenium.Click("css=.contactName ~ .contactName");
```

If these two nodes don't share the same parent, you'll probably have to go with an XPath locator instead of CSS:

```
selenium.Click("xpath=//*[@class='contactName'][2]");
```

Comment: They are not under the same parent. So I think i'll go with xpath. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @aahrens: Without knowing what the HTML looks like, I can only offer a very generic XPath solution.

Comment: No problem, I just changed the * to input since I wanted the second input with the class 'contactName'