# CSS to select nearest descendent?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using CSS, is there any way to select an element's nearest descendent that matches a certain selector?

```
<div class="foo"> <!-- if we're inside this -->
  <div>
    <br />
    <div class="bar"> <!-- match this -->
      <div class="bar"> <!-- but not this -->
        <div class="bar"> <!-- or this -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar"> <!-- I don't really care whether we match this -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is, something that would select the first `.bar` within any `.foo` (no matter how many child or sibling elements are in between), but not the second or third `.bar`.

Comment: If you have a second `.bar` that is a sibling to the one you want selected, do you want it selected as well?

Comment: Ideally no, but that would also be acceptable.

Comment: Will there only ever be one `bar`, with all other `bar`s contained within it?

Comment: @animuson: I think you're asking the same thing as Paul, right?

Comment: Here's the only thing I can think of: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gqJdP/. A bit hacky.

Comment: @JW I think you need to edit your question with a more robust test case and a clear indication of which items should and should not be matched.

Comment: @thirtydot: evil yet brilliant.

Comment: My suggestion is viable, although distasteful, *if* you can place an upper limit on the possible number of parents between `.foo` and the `.bar` you want to match. Even if you had to repeat the selector (let's say) 10 times, it's not too bad.

Comment: @thirtydot Nice! I was thinking along those lines but couldn't get it quite right haha. You should post that as an answer and I will upvote for sure!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's my hacktastic answer: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gqJdP/2/

```css
/*repeat for as many levels as there could be*/
.foo > .bar,
.foo > :not(.bar) > .bar,
.foo > :not(.bar) > :not(.bar) > .bar {
    border-color: blue;
}
.bar {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Quoting myself from a comment:

My suggestion is viable, although distasteful, *if* you can place an upper limit on the possible number of parents between `.foo` and the `.bar` you want to match. Even if you had to repeat the selector (let's say) 10 times, it's not too bad.

Comment: Fan-hackin'-tastic! I would hate to use this in my own CSS haha :)

Comment: @StephRose: Not quite. Examine the selector carefully. I assume that it's a direct child of `.foo`, or a direct child of anything that isn't `.bar` that's a direct child of `.foo`, or *<inception joke here>*.

Comment: @thirtydot Hah! Now I see that. I think I must be braindead today. I've never heard of `:not`, that's pretty neat. This was a good lesson for me. Also, I hope the OP isn't going more than 5 levels deep.... <inception joke>

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do what you are asking for *completely* using only CSS. You can select the `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`, but not `the-nth-item-matching-this-selector`.

As "proof", review the list of CSS3 selectors available (which covers all the capabilities of CSS1 and CSS2.1):
http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

You will need to use JavaScript (on the client) or server-side manipulation (e.g. annotating the first such item with a special class).

---

**Edit**: Based on your edit, you can do:

```
.foo .bar      { font-weight:bold; color:red }
.foo .bar .bar { font-weight:normal; color:black }
```

i.e. you need to explicitly "undo" the styling applied on ancestors that would be inherited. This is "fragile"—if you change a style on an ancestor you need to be sure to also change the value on the corresponding "override" rule—but effective.

And, if @thirtydot posts his hack as an answer, we can all accept that, too.

*Although it probably does not help, note also that you can accomplish this goal [with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665441/select-an-nth-matched-node-from-a-list-of-matching-nodes).*

Comment: We're supposed to get `nth-matching` in CSS4 (whenever that is), but I don't see how that would help in this case.

Comment: @animuson With `nth-matching` it would just be `.foo .bar:nth-matching(1)`, right?

Comment: Good suggestion about undoing.

Answer (score -4):

This should only get the first child element of `.foo`:

```
.foo > .bar
```

And not select any farther down the chain.

Comment: -1 As shown in the example code, the .bar is **not** necessarily a direct child.

Comment: True. Didn't see that. Not that divs should be inside p tags anyway.

Comment: @StephRose: Yes, you're right about that. I fixed it in the demo in my answer.